# Sharepoint 2007: SharePoint list data -> HTML

Tags: html, xml, sharepoint, fusioncharts

I have a SharePoint page that displays an [Angular Gauge](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/widgets/Contents/Angular/Overview.html) from FusionCharts XT using a Page Viewer Web Part. Here is the HTML that the Page Viewer is linked to:

```
<object width="400" height="300" id="Column3D" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0">
  <param name="movie" value="http://somepath/AngularGauge.swf"/>
  <param name="FlashVars" value="&chartWidth=400&chartHeight=300&DOMId=myChartIdRegisterWithJS=1&debugMode=0&dataXML=<chart lowerLimit='0' upperLimit='100' lowerLimitDisplay='Bad' upperLimitDisplay='Good' gaugeStartAngle='180' gaugeEndAngle='0' palette='1' numberSuffix='%25' tickValueDistance='20' showValue='1'>
   <colorRange>
      <color minValue='0' maxValue='75' code='FF654F'/>
      <color minValue='75' maxValue='90' code='F6BD0F'/>
      <color minValue='90' maxValue='100' code='8BBA00'/>
   </colorRange>
   <dials>
      <dial value='92' rearExtension='10'/>
   </dials>
</chart>">
  <param name="quality" value="high"/>
  <embed src="http://somepath/AngularGauge.swf" flashVars="&chartWidth=400&chartHeight=300&DOMId=myChartIdRegisterWithJS=1&debugMode=0&dataXML=<chart lowerLimit='0' upperLimit='100' lowerLimitDisplay='Bad' upperLimitDisplay='Good' gaugeStartAngle='180' gaugeEndAngle='0' palette='1' numberSuffix='%' tickValueDistance='20' showValue='1'>
   <colorRange>
      <color minValue='0' maxValue='75' code='FF654F'/>
      <color minValue='75' maxValue='90' code='F6BD0F'/>
      <color minValue='90' maxValue='100' code='8BBA00'/>
   </colorRange>
   <dials>
      <dial value='92' rearExtension='10'/>
   </dials>
</chart>" width="400" height="300" name="AngularGauge" quality="high" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"/>
</object>
```

What I want to do is replace what is inside those `colorRange` and `dials` tags with data pulled from a SharePoint list, probably with maxValueYellow, maxValueRed, and dialValue fields (or similar). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible. You can, for example, use JavaScript to get the data from the list and then populate your HTML code. To get the data from a Sharepoint list I recommand you to use a third party library like [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) or [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/).